# Limit $\lim_{x \to -2^- } \frac{a - e^\frac{1}{x+2}}{2e^\frac{1}{x+2} - 1}$

Tags: limits

According to  my friend you put $ x=-2-h$ directly and say that it becomes like $ e^{\frac{-1}{0}}$ is $-\infty$ , he says that this is justified because x is tending to that limit however from what I've learned you can't directly put $ x=0$ when you have functions like $ \frac{1}{x}$

However, I do know that we can evaluate at limits inform of $ \frac{0}{0}$ because they are
'indeterminate' rather than undefined. Where exactly is the gap in my knowledge and how do I solve this limit in a more rigorous way ( Taylor series or l'hospital) without using facts like $\lim_{x \to 0^{+}} \frac{1}{x}= \infty$

edit: minus one the two is meaning exponent approaching from negative side

im saying -2 from the left side – , Idk how to latex it

Comment: Are you sure its not $\lim_{x\to -2^-}$

Comment: yes sir thank you very much

Comment: you are very welcome sir but i do not think your question is very good sir

Comment: This was indeed not such a great question sir ;D @ICanKindOfCode

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My suggestion would be to substitute $x+2=-1/t$, so your limit becomes
$$
\lim_{t\to\infty}\frac{a-e^{-t}}{2e^{-t}-1}
$$
Now the numerator has limit $a$ and the denominator has limit $-1$, so you get $a/(-1)=-a$.

It would be different if the limit is for $x\to-2^+$. With the substitution $x+2=1/t$, the limit becomes
$$
\lim_{t\to\infty}\frac{a-e^t}{2e^t-1}=\lim_{t\to\infty}\frac{ae^{-t}-1}{2-e^{-t}}=-\frac{1}{2}
$$

Comment: the left hand limit is -a

Comment: @DDD4C4U Yes, as said in the answer, the limit is $a/(-1)=-a$. Added for clarity.

Answer (score 0):

As $x$ goes to $-2$ from the left, the fraction goes to negative infinity, so the exponential goes to 0. Since there are no conflicts with that in the denominator in the function, we get that the limit is $\frac{a}{-1}=-a$

N.B. A little tex advice. When typing e to some complicated power, you want to put curly brackets around the exponent such as this

$e^{\frac{1}{x+2}}$

where the code is e^{\frac{1}{x+2}}

Comment: im saying -2 from the left side

Comment: Yes, I just read your edit :)